# Convert a java string classpath into a wildcard where more than `N` jars from the same directory show up in the classpath?

Tags: java, classpath

I launch java from an agent launcher. The class path gets so large I need to use the manifest.mf file or Windows will run out of cmd line space (bash has a limit too but it's much higher so we don't see it there).

I'd rather just use wildcard on the classpath.

How can I write a java method that can convert the a string classpath (example: `/my/dir/myjar.jar /my/dir/myjar2.jar ...`) into a wildcard where more than `N` jars from the same directory show up in the classpath?

Comment: From the command-line can you use `/my/dir/*.jar`?

Comment: Why? Using the manifest is simpler, more secure, and doesn't present this problem.

Comment: Simpler is a relative term and the file itself is causing some drama.

Comment: And @Code-Apprentice no i'm tweaking my answer below. it doesn't quite work yet will get it working today

Comment: No actually after looking at it some more @EJP is right. sometimes the best advise comes from the comments

Comment: The problem wasn't with the manifest it was with the agent code that is written not doing what it's supposed to with said classpath

Answer (score -1):

Here is what i'm working out:

```
public static String convertClasspathToWildcard(String cp) {
    Set<String> parentCountMap = new HashSet<>();
    for (String nextJar : cp.split(SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS && cp.contains(";") ? ";" : ":")) {
      String substring = nextJar.substring(0, nextJar.lastIndexOf(File.separator));
      parentCountMap.add(substring);
    }
    StringBuilder newCp = new StringBuilder();
    for (String parent : parentCountMap) {
      if (newCp.length() > 0) {
        newCp.append(SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS ? ";" : ":");
      }
      newCp.append(parent + File.separator + "*");
    }
    return newCp.toString();
  }
```

Doesn't quite work but it's the idea I'm going for.